# Standard deviation always larger than the mean -- implications

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

I was working on a series of calculations, and in my work, I came to the conclusion that (with some help from Jensen's inequality) that the following property holds:

$$\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)} > \mathbb{E}(X) > 0$$

where $X$ is a random variable such that $X>0$.

To be clear, $\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)} > \mathbb{E}(X)$ is not always true in the general case, but what I mean to say is that in my specific problem it is always true.

What I would like to know, is if there are any implications when the standard deviation is always greater than the mean? The only thing I could think of was that it would imply that the coefficient of variation (CV %) is always greater than 100%, but is that useful?

Comment: "Any implications" provides no guidance concerning how to answer your question.  Could you reframe it in terms of the objective of your calculations, perhaps?

Comment: It says what it says and there are many circumstances in which it is true. For example any variable whatsoever that has negative or zero mean (and isn't constant) has SD that is greater than the mean.  The statement about coefficient of variation isn't true either, as with a negative mean the CV is negative and so less than zero.  That could be answered by excluding that case on some ground or another, but I think your question needs details about your work to allow better replies.

Comment: @NickCox sorry I unintentionally omitted the fact $\mathbb{E}(X)>0$ always.

Comment: OK, so that needs to be in the question, but I have to fear that it's got some way to go.

Comment: @NickCox That's fine. I won't follow-up on this further.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true. Consider $X$ as the absolute value of a variable from the $N(1000, 1)$ distribution. It has $E[X]\approx 1000$ and $\sqrt{\mathrm{var}[X]}\approx 1$, so $\sqrt{\mathrm{var}[X]}<E[X]$

What is true is $\sqrt{E[X^2]}\geq E[X]$.

Comment: Sorry, I will rewrite my question. I did not mean to imply that $$\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)} > \mathbb{E}(X)$$ holds in general. I meant to say in hat in the problem I am working on its true, and since in my case its always true, what are the implications.